# How to handle spaces in filenames in Git Bash

Tags: windows, git-bash

I have written the following script to run under Git Bash under Windows 7:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
for logfile in `find -name "*.log" -o -name "*.err" -o -name "*.out"`
do
    echo $logfile
    grep "api/" "$logfile"
done
```

The problem is that grep chokes when a filename has a space in it. I thought the double quotes should take care of that, but it is not co-operating.

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Solution 1

The closest solution is to use `find` with `-print0` and read the output with `while read …`:

```
find -name "*.log" -o -name "*.err" -o -name "*.out" -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' logfile; do
    ...
```

Continue using `"$logfile"` with quotes, as you always should when using variables.

#### Solution 2

Another solution would be to not use `find` at all and just let `grep` run on multiple files:

```
shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s globstar
grep "api/" **/*.log **/*.err **/*.out
```

Here, `globstar` enables recursive matching of directories with `**`. You should set `nullglob` to prevent errors if one of these file extensions do not exist.

This only works for a limited set of files though, as you may reach the maximum length of command line arguments.

#### Why does the error happen?

You should never run `for` on the output of `find` (or `ls`, or any other function that outputs filenames with whitespace). Read [this article](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for more info on why this is a problem and what can be done to solve it.

In short, Bash splits arguments by whitespace. Imagine you have three files, `a`, `foo bar` and `b`, then the line would evalute to:

```
for logfile in a foo bar b; do
```

Obviously, Bash will set `logfile` to `a`, `foo`, `bar`, and `b`, which is not what you wanted. If you could manually specify the input to `for`, you'd wrap these filenames in quotes to solve the problem.

For doing this automatically, the solution is to delimit these filenames with a `NUL` character (which is what the `-print0` option does) and then split the output based on that `NUL` character again (which is what the `-d ''` in `read` does).

Comment: As long as you don't have newlines in your files (and I'll admit, the most general scripts OUGHT to accept these...), `ls` might work, as long as you use a `while IFS=$'\t' read` loop instead of a 'for i in` loop. [Here's where I found `IFS=$'\t'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9736732/1048186)